# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Productpages'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I m working on a Django project this is my first project so i don't understand Django well
I create a app called pages and add it to settings.py
I add a home view to views.py And I added it to url prattens
But i got this error

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/mihin/PycharmProjects/Gshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mihin/PycharmProjects/Gshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/mihin/PycharmProjects/Gshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/mihin/PycharmProjects/Gshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/mihin/PycharmProjects/Gshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mihin/PycharmProjects/Gshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mihin/PycharmProjects/Gshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/mihin/PycharmProjects/Gshop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Productpages'
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your pages here.
def home(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'products.html', {})
```

Here is my view.py it is pretty basic

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pages import view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', view.home, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Urls.py

I cant figure out whats the problem
[File tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbxPp.png)

Comment: you are missing comma between Product and pages in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Are you importing `Productpages` somewhere? or did you put `Productpages` in your installed apps? Looks to be a typo of putting two app names together.

Comment: oh found the error thank you all.Its the missing comma